# Blazor WASM projects will not run

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Creating a new Blazor WASM project will not run using dotnet run or Visual Studio non-debug mode.  It will run in Visual Studio debug.  Blazor server works properly.  I do my development using VS debug mode, so I have no idea how long this has been broken.

The browser tools shows an exception while running WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args); in Program.cs

Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.UriParser' threw an exception.

Any ideas?  I am really stuck on this!

Thanks

I have tried reinstalling .NET sdks, Visual Studio, but am unable to fix this.

Comment: Have a look here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typeinitializationexception?view=net-6.0 . I would look into the : A missing assembly or data file section --> ...assembly or data file that was present in an application's development and test environments is missing from its runtime environment.  Also look into --> ...The InnerException property of TypeInitializationException holds the underlying exception.

Answer (score -1):

Well, don't I feel like an idiot.  I spent all this time trying to fix the development environment, and in a last act of desperation, I tried a repair on the Edge browser...and that fixed it.

Sometimes it is better to be lucky than good...